# Unknown error coming while trying to load the liferay page

Tags: java, liferay

I am getting the following error when I try to load page which has got 2 portlets deployed and has a theme

```
16:49:13,300 ERROR [http-bio-8080-exec-23][ThemeUtil:445] _SERVLET_CONTEXT_/templates/portal_normal.vm does not exist
```

What might be the reaon for this?

I am not able to load the page itself. Please help.

Comment: Have a read of https://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/6656290

Comment: Yes I read it.. I couldn't get something out of it. It was not helpful for me:(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that your theme is not deployed properly.

Undeploy the custom-theme that is applied to the page, then try loading the page if the page loads than it is confirmed it is the theme which was causing the issue.

If the issue still persist restart the server and then check if the page loads. After this deploy your custom-theme again.

Sometimes you would require to clear the `temp` folder as well since it retains stale data which can cause problems like these.

This should give you some lead to find out the solution.

Answer (score 0):

It happened to me and what i did was i continuously stopped , started the server again and again. Then i did ant build lot of times and it automatically got solved. ITs just some kind of conflict which we could not resolve.

Answer (score 0):

Try restarting your liferay server then  re-deploy.